# JPanel and JFrame are different sizes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

In the code below, I create a `JFrame`, set the size to 800 by 800 pixels, set the layout to `BorderLayout`, then add a `JPanel`.

In the `JPanel`, I use `paintComponent` to draw a 20x20 pixel image in 7 locations. 
At position 0-0, the icon appears in the upper right corner.

The icon is 20 pixels high, and the frame and panel are both 800 pixels high, so drawing the icon at x-780 should align the icon with the bottom of the window. But the icond doesn't even appear.

The remaining icons are drawn a x-770, x-760, x-758, and x-750. x-758 appears aligned with the bottom of the window. So I conclude that x[0] on the `JPanel` start at the `JFrame`'s x[42]

I think I've set the `BorderLayout` correctly. I do call `setSize()` in the `JPanel`'s constructor. I thought setting an explicit size might screw it up. But after commenting that line out, the program shows the same behavior.

Can you show me what I'm doing wrong?

**Frametest.java**

```
package frametest;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FrameTest extends JFrame{
    public static final int HEIGHT = 800;
    public static final int WIDTH = 800;

    public FrameTest(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new Panel(WIDTH, HEIGHT), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setTitle("Frame Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FrameTest();
    }
}
```

**Panel.java**

```
package frametest;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel{
    private int height;
    private int width;
    Image icon1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("icon1.png")).getImage();     //Note that the png file is 20 x 20 pixels.   

    public Panel(int width, int hieght){
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        //setSize(width, hieght);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(icon1, 0, 0, this);   //appears in the upper-right corner
        g2d.drawImage(icon1, 20, 780, this);  //does not appear
        g2d.drawImage(icon1, 40, 770, this);  //appears with bottom pixels cut off
        g2d.drawImage(icon1, 70, 760, this);  //appears with the bottom pixels cut off
        g2d.drawImage(icon1, 100, 758, this);  //appears aligned with bottom of the window
        g2d.drawImage(icon1, 130, 750, this);  //appears slightly above the bottom of the window
        g2d.drawImage(icon1, 780, 20, this);  //appears aligned with the right side of the screen.
    }
}
```

Comment: What I have suggested you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the size of the `JFrame`. This includes the Frame Decoration, the Menu Bar (if you have one), and so on. If you want your JPanel to have the Dimensions `800 x 800`, set the preferred Size of your JPanel and use `JFrame.pack()`.

To do so, remove the following line from `Frametest.java`:

```java
setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

Then, in `Panel.java`, change this line from

```java
//setSize(width, hieght);
```

to:

```java
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
```

Instead of this, you can also overwrite `getPreferredSize()`:

```java
public Dimension getPreferredSize ()
{
    return new Dimension(800, 800);
}
```

Comment: Fascinating. All this time I was trying to get the Panel to adjust to the Frame size. I should have made the Frame adjust to the Panel (and other elements later) size. Thank you very much.

Comment: On a side note, I had to pass a Dimension to setPrefferedSize ( setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height)); ). It wouldn't accept two integers. That was a simple enough change.

Comment: @MichaelCornn Thanks for pointing out that little mistake, I corrected it

Answer (score 1):

- Use `frame.pack()` (as you are already using) instead of `frame.setSize()` that fits the components as per component's preferred size. Just remove `setSize()` calls.
- Override `getPreferredSize()` to set the preferred size of the `JPanel` in case of custom painting.

sample code:

```
class Panel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(..., ...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the problem is because of the border around the JFrame. Things like the menu bar at the top will take away some space from the available space to display things in the JFrame.

Try adding `getPreferredSize()` to your JPanel, and calling `pack()` on your JFrame.